# ASP.NET site won't start under IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-8, iis-8

ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2010, Windows 8, IIS 8.

I have an ASP.NET site that I pulled from my client's source control. It runs fine under the Visual Studio Development Server but a few things don't work correctly when it's not running under IIS.

When I set it up to run in IIS, it initially gave me a 500 error due to IIS_IUSRS not having permission to read the web.config.

I fixed that, and now it starts, but the browser just sits there saying 'Connecting' indefinitely if I browse to the site - it doesn't even time out.

If I try to launch it from VS, it does something similar except after a while times out and says that it can't attach the debugger. I've read the various posts here and elsewhere about that 'can't attach debugger' message and either they don't apply to me or the proposed solutions don't make any difference.

I've checked the normal IIS logs, enabled Failed Request Tracing and checked those - nothing, it doesn't seem to even get that far. I've tried changing the application pool settings etc. and that doesn't make any difference.

Can anybody suggest anything else that I can try in order to figure out what's happening here?

Comment: My guess is it was built on an older framework that you do not have installed on your windows 8 machine.

Comment: The application pool is running. The app pool should be the correct version, but out of desperation I've tried all 4 possible configurations. The app pool identity appears to have the right access. web.config looks OK. Virtual folder is set up. Fiddler just lists the initial request which never returns anything. I have the right framework versions.

Comment: If Fiddler shows that there is no response, please try to see if there is any entry corresponding to this access in IIS logs. That might provide some hints on what happens. If the request is stuck in the IIS processing pipeline, there is no easy way to debug except live debugging or dump analysis.

Comment: @nrkn sorry for disturbing but I'm getting the same error while trying to run my django app with IIS have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I acknowledge that you have already said that you have tried changing your app pool settings. However, you didn't say *which* settings you tried.

I generally touch the following whenever I set up an IIS Site:

- .NET Framework Version
- Enable 32-bit applications (I frequently to work with managed dlls that are 32-bit only)
- Managed Pipeline Mode
- Identity

Double check/play with the values you have for these settings under IIS.

Another thing worth checking is your sessionState element in your web.config. In my experience an incorrectly configured sessionState gives a google-able error, but it is plausible to me that there could be something going on with session persistence that hasn't been fully persisted into your website.

Also consider your impersonation. Again: In my experience an incorrect impersonation will error quickly. But if you're using a domain account then it seems plausible that this could be failing to resolve and causing your app pool to hang.

How are you deploying to IIS? Are you dumping your source code into IIS, or are you compiling and publishing a Web Application? Whichever of the two you are trying, consider trying the other.

Are you putting up a release build or a debug build of your web application? Whichever you're trying that is in error, give the other a try and see if that works.

Be mindful of security here: Test giving your app pool an administrator identity. This is a bad solution in the long run, but if your website works when running under an administrator account then this would narrow down your problem area to being permissions related.

That's all I can think of to try given the information presented so far. Can you think of anything else that might be relevant?

Comment: OK - I've tried various app pool configurations as per what you've outlined above, with no luck. I had previously tried them all but not thought about enable 32 bit, unfortunately it didn't help.

There's no sessionState in web.config.

I hadn't tried to deploy via publish - I'm trying to do that now but it's just sitting there, the output window shows that it's started but it's not doing anything. The activity indicator thingy in the status bar is going however.

Changing the app pool identity didn't help.

My system is pretty standard and I haven't had any issues with IIS prior to this.

Comment: I have a strong gut feeling that the publish just sitting there indefinitely, no timeout, no errors, just sits there, relates to the site just sitting there saying 'connecting' with no timeouts or errors. I'm just not sure where to go next with this.

Comment: This might be a stupid question: Do you actually have an IIS process running for your app pool in Task Manager? Look for w3wp.exe under 'Show processes from all users' to check.

Comment: There are no stupid questions, especially for something this ineffable - but yes, I do.

Comment: Another test: Under IIS, try dropping in a website that just consists of a 'Default.htm' page with some basic HTML in it. Check that this can be viewed. Should at least indicate whether the problem is IIS application pool settings or if it's something to do with the code you're running.

Comment: Coming up against the edge of my potentially useful suggestions, sorry. :(

Comment: Yeah, works fine. I'd suspect the code too except it runs OK under the vs dev server, and it runs under IIS (7.5?) on the deployment server (Server 2012?)